# Need to display data as it is returned using web service/jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, webforms

I have an operation (That I can't change) that starts threads that make calls to our Oracle database to see if a certain hotel(s) has availability on a certain date.

If a date/hotel combination has availability, that thread returns information about the date/hotel in the form of a DataTable that is merged into a Main DataTable of results.  Yes, I know ... I inherited this.

So I am trying to re-write this operation.  I still must query Oracle in threads to get the availability information, but I want to display the data as it is returned (in chunks of 5, 10? I'm flexible), instead of having the user sit in front of the screen for up to 4 minutes before a complete result is spat out into a GridView.

How do I do this directly from an .aspx page so I can make a web service call and populate a grid (JqGrid?) with the results?

If I haven't provided enough information or described what I am trying to achieve, please let me know and I will elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle provides a field on each row called "rowid" 
(http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/rowid.html)

The first time you send the query, send in the int (x) to define what the highest rownumber you want is.  Have the service return the total number of rows and the first x rows.

Then, the 2nd time you send the query, get the next x rows, rinse and repeat.

Basically, you need to send an ajax query for rows x through y each time until you have them all loaded.

I would recommend paging as well, since users typically don't want to see hundreds of results at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get rowid back, as I am calling Oracle stored procedures that cannot be changed at this time.  But the threads that perform the Oracle calls are chunked out like you describe.  Each thread can only return one row (which sucks), but it is what I have to deal with.  So, instead of letting all of these threads go at once, I can break them up into groups - but what do I return?  An array of an object?  And while I keep calling my web service to return items, how do I append the results to something like a jqgrid? Sample code and links are great, this is my first attempt

Comment: at something like this. I know some javascript, but it is not my forte.

Comment: What you will return is JSON, which looks like this:
[
{ myProperty: "Value", anotherProperty: 1234 }, 
{ myProperty:"Value", anotherProperty:2343} 
]

The square brackets denote an array, an each object is wrapped in curly braces.  But you don't want to build this manually, use the DataContractJSONSerializer that .NET provides.

On the javascript end, use JSON.parse to convert the string into actual Javascript objects (Javascript Object Notation = JSON).

Comment: About JqGrid, it uses a declarative model, you tell the url where it can get the JSON from (in string format) and the columns, and it will display them in the grid.  http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html